# Clear inline style after reset

Tags: javascript

How do I remove the inline style which is added by JavaScript?

For example: if people click the button, the marginTop of div`#test` will be 30px, but what if I want to remove the inline style instead of resetting it to another value like 0?

**I do not want to add a class to that element and remove it because it's not suitable in my use case.**

```js
const elm = document.querySelector('#test')

function change() {
  elm.style.marginTop = '30px';
}
```

```css
#test {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either set as empty string

```
elm.style.marginTop = '';
```

or to remove the complete attribute use

[removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

```
elem.removeAttribute('style');
```